# Is Qatar Airways' hand baggage size strictly enforced?

Tags: hand-luggage, qatar-airways

Qatar Airways states on [their](https://www.qatarairways.com/en/baggage/allowance.html) homepage:

> Maximum dimensions for each piece of hand baggage are 50x37x25cm
>   (20x15x10in)

The height of my hand baggage measures 55 cm; sort of 50 cm large body + gears.
Does ground personnel strictly enforce the 50 cm?

If yes, how much fee do I need to pay (couldn't find this on their website)?

Comment: Generally nobody is going to enforce a 5cm excess in real life specially for Hand luggage. They don't really have time to deal with such a small limit cross. On every flight I take I see some people having difficulty trying to put their bags in the overhead bin. If there were strict checks most of them would be out. There is some small room beyond the limits advertised

Comment: They could enforce it by having a sample box- fit in the box and it is fine otherwise rejected.

Comment: No! PS: Have traveled in Qatar Airways multiple times and have been in such situations before.

Comment: If you can break the rules with 5 cm more, can I break the rules with 9 cm more?  Personally I wish airlines enforced carry on rules down to the centimeter and kilogram.

Comment: I have never seen it being enforced on a dozen or so Qatar airlines flights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen it being enforced on a dozen or so Qatar airlines flights.

And I've seen people obviously exceeding limits, especially on flights between Doha and India (some to the point where it doesn't even fit into the overhead bin and has to be checked).

Comment: Thanks! Indeed my hand luggage was neither weighted nor measured. Like I mentioned above, it was just a slightly over the limits. Actually, I haven't seen any size measurement boxes either.